# .NET Core 2.1 console app running via Windows Task Scheduler with HttpClient calls result in 401

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've been running into an issue in upgrading an application from .NET Core 1.0.1 to .NET Core 2.1. This is a console app running via the Windows Task Scheduler that calls a set of web services hosted in IIS on the same server. After the upgrade, when attempting to run it on the host machine, it fails on the first API call, which returns a 401. IIS is set up to accept Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication, with the Negotiate and NTLM providers. The task scheduler sets the user that the console app should use. The code that makes the first API call looks like the following:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
   handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

   var client = new HttpClient(handler);
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   var result = await client.GetStringAsync(myUrlString);
   return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyResponseObject>>(result);
 }
```

I've also upgraded the API project to .NET Core 2.1, but I tried reverting back to the 1.0.1 version while running the console app as 2.1 (and conversely, running the API at 2.1 and the console app at 1.0.1 also works) to be sure that it's the console app with the problem.

The console app works fine when running from my localhost with the API hosted locally in IIS Express.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's recorded as sub status in IIS log files? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: I don't think it's valid to do both Anonymous and Windows authentication in the same IIS site.

Comment: The substatus code is 1 - Logon failed.

Comment: @mason All of our sites hosted in IIS currently have both enabled (including the site that is hosting the .NET Core v1.0.1 version of the API, which the console app also has the same problem when trying to hit it). In any case, just tried disabling anonymous and rerunning the console app but still no dice.

Comment: Did you make sure the user has the correct permissions to use your app? Is "run with highest privileges" checked in the task scheduler?

Comment: Yup. It's the same task I used for the previous version, which still runs successfully when I load up the old assemblies. And I made sure via logging that the same user is being used by the app as it was previously.

Comment: Does `myUrlString` is secured by windows identity? How did you run .net core from task scheduler? If you manually launch `.net core console app`, will it hit 401 error? First, make sure you run .net core under windows account.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean regarding the url string being secured by windows identity and running .NET Core under a windows account? I am publishing the app as self-contained rather than installing .NET Core on the machine. When I run the console app from the command line, I do hit the 401 error, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It work for our client app.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .Accept
      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to work. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue a few weeks ago, when moving from .NET Framework 4.6.x to .NET Core 2.1. The problem may be connected with new HttpHandler implemented in .NET Core 2.1. There are various issues with this handler (for example, [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32328)). Even though this particular bug may not be completely related, the workaround described there may help:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```